# Why doesn't FormatNumber() display leading zero for a fraction whatever value is passed for IncludeLeadingDigit?

Tags: vbscript, number-formatting

The following code:

```
WScript.Echo FormatNumber(0.123, 0)
WScript.Echo FormatNumber(0.123, 1)
WScript.Echo FormatNumber(0.123, 2)
WScript.Echo FormatNumber(0.123, 0, TristateTrue)
WScript.Echo FormatNumber(0.123, 1, TristateTrue)
WScript.Echo FormatNumber(0.123, 2, TristateTrue)
WScript.Echo FormatNumber(0.123, 0, TristateFalse)
WScript.Echo FormatNumber(0.123, 1, TristateFalse)
WScript.Echo FormatNumber(0.123, 2, TristateFalse)
WScript.Echo FormatNumber(0.123, 0, TristateUseDefault)
WScript.Echo FormatNumber(0.123, 1, TristateUseDefault)
WScript.Echo FormatNumber(0.123, 2, TristateUseDefault)
```

outputs as:

```
0
0,1
0,12

,1
,12

,1
,12

,1
,12
```

Can anyone explain me why passing `TristateTrue` makes no difference with `TristateFalse` - or `TristateUseDefault` as well - ?

FYI:

> `FormatNumber(Expression [,NumDigitsAfterDecimal [,IncludeLeadingDigit [,UseParensForNegativeNumbers [,GroupDigits]]]])`
>
> *IncludeLeadingDigit*
>
> Optional. Tristate constant that indicates whether or not a leading zero is displayed for fractional values. See Settings section for values.

BTW here are my computer's regional settings (I should have my leading zero!!!) on a Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (French):

[image: My regional formats on a Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (French)]

Comment: You _did_ declare the constants right? `Const TristateUseDefault = -2 : Const TristateTrue = -1 : Const TristateFalse= 0`

Comment: OK, now you've got it! I do declare them... but in my main script, not in this script I'm using to test this feature... x-(
Too bad these constants aren't declared as oter default vbXXX ones...

Comment: That's rather strange because these `Tristate` constants are shared amongst FormatCurrency/FormatNumber/FormatPercent and OpenTextFile/OpenAsTextStream methods.

Comment: @Theo would you like to suggest an answer so I can validate it? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I just posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, my comment as answer:

You need to define these constants in the script:

```
Const TristateUseDefault = -2
Const TristateTrue = -1
Const TristateFalse = 0
```

As tip: by starting off your scripts with `Option Explicit`, errors about undefined variables will show up.